# Separating model from UI

Tags: java, design, ui, swing, model

I have a Swing application with a custom TreeModel that can refer to domain instances. I'm wondering what changes I could make if I consider moving to a web interface later on. Would a pluggable model be considered as good design? What would you do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pluggable model, using MVC (at a larger system level than what Swing defines MVC as), or a facade pattern would all work